Error Ajax 404 en conexión a DB MySql
Si cargo una tabla hardcodeada en HTML con DataTable no hay problema y funciona bien.
HTML:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/js/dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#users').DataTable();
    });

</script>

Hasta aquí el resultado es perfecto, pero si llamo con Ajax a una función del controller para conectar con la DB, me da error 404. Ni siquiera llega a entrar en el controller.
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#users').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '<?= base_url("home/get_datatables") ?>',
                type: 'get',
            },
            columns: [
                {data: "id"},
                {data: "username"},
                {data: "status"},
                {data: "active"},
                {data: "perPage"},
                {data: "locale"},
                {data: "last_active"},
                {data: "created_at"},
                {data: "updated_at"},
                {data: "deleted_at"}
            ]
        });

    });

</script>

En en controller Home está la función get_datatables() que ejecuta la consulta a la tabla en la DB, pero como decía, no llega ni a entra en la función por el error 404.
Esta es la función:
public function get_datatables()
{

    $valor_buscado = $this->request->getGet('search')['value'];

    $table_map = [
        0 => 'id',
        1 => 'username',
        2 => 'status',
        3 => 'active',
        4 => 'perPage',
        5 => 'locale',
        6 => 'last_active',
        7 => 'created_at',
        8 => 'updated_at',
        9 => 'deleted_at'
    ];

    $sql_count = "SELECT count(id) AS total FROM users";
    $sql_data = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $condition = "";

    if(!empty($valor_buscado)) {
        foreach ($table_map as $key => $val) {
            if($table_map[$key] == 'id') {
                $condition .= "WHERE " . $val . " LIKE '%" . $valor_buscado . "%'";
            } else {
                $condition .= "OR " . $val . " LIKE '%" . $valor_buscado . "%'";
            }
        }
    }

    $sql_count = $sql_count . $condition;
    $sql_data = $sql_data . $condition;

    $total_count = $this->db->query($sql_count)->getRow();

    $sql_data .= "ORDER BY " . $table_map[$this->request->getGet('order')[0]['column']] . "
    " . $this->request->getGet('order')[0]['dir'] . " LIMIT " . $this->request->getGet('start').",
    " . $this->request->getGet('length') . "";

    $data = $this->db->query($sql_data)->getResult();

    $json_data = [
        'draw' => intval($this->request->getGet('draw')),
        'recordsTotal' => $total_count->total,
        'recordsFiltered' => $total_count->total,
        'data' => $data
    ];

    echo json_encode($json_data);


}

Se agradecen ideas.

Como tienes definida la ruta?

No hay una ruta definida. Creo que no hace falta porque la llamada Ajax a la función es desde el script de la vista welcome_message.php que la carga el propio index.php que se llama cuando accedes a la app. ¿Es correcto asi?

La ruta que intentas llamar debe estar definida en el archivo app/Config/Routes.php a menos que tengas habilitada la opción de Auto Routing.
La ruta se debe definir de la siguiente forma $routes->get('home/get_datatables', 'Home::get_datatables');

Ya no había intentado y vi que sequía el 404. Lo he vuelto a intentar y pasa lo mismo. Gracias igual! Esta es parte de la petición que se ve en el navegador Mozilla 'http://localhost/datatables/public/home/get_datatables?draw=1&columns[0][data' Es correcta, pero nada.

Si estas pasando otros valores por GET entonces tu ruta se debe establecer así:
$routes->get('home/get_datatables?(:any)', 'Home::get_datatables/$1');

Los valores que se pasen a la función de deben recibir así:
$search = $this->request->getGet("search");


No le paso ningún valor. Este 'search' es el campo de de búsqueda que por defecto ofrece DataTables, y para guardar su valor en una variable se instancia así '$valor_buscado = $this->request->getGet('search')['value'];'. Esto lo en visto en un video de formación. Aquí el problema sigue en la petición ajax y el 404.

La ruta que te compartí es precisamente para eso, yo la uso para lo mismo que intentas hacer, una solicitud con datatables usando AJAX. ?(:any) representa todo el código adicional que agrega datatables a la petición.

La he incluido en Raoutes.php y sigue el 404. Creo que he revisado todo lo que corresponde a configuración, incluyendo .env
'# DATABASE
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = datatables
database.default.username = root' ... y si fuese algún link o script? Seguiré buscando a ver

No recuerdo que haya un archivo llamado Raoutes.php creo que desde ahí está el problema

El problema estaba en la definición de la ruta en ajax. Solo hace falta poner la ruta relativa y no la absoluta:
ajax: {
            url: 'home/get_datatables',
            type: 'get'
        }

